# VBScript handing a sql value of 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql, vbscript

I have a problem that I cannot figure out.  I am sure it si simple for the experts.  I have a sql datetime field that is populated with a value of NULL or 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.  I just need an if statment to check for both.  I have tried: isNUll, eqaul to null, equal to nothing, equal to "".  But  they keep missing the value of 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.

```
If IsNull(MyDate) or MyDate = "" then
   'Do Something
end if
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try changing your MyDate = "" part to a comparison like MyDate < '1910-10-10' (compare against a date that's prior to any possible dates in the database) ?

Comment: Does MyDate have a type of Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just looking for #1900-01-01#...

```
If IsNull(MyDate) or MyDate = "" or MyDate = #1900-01-01# Then
   'Do Something
End If
```